Need to controll calling 3rd party API calling per minute (throttling) in .net core
I am consuming 3rd party API in my service. My service is been called by azure service bus trigger function.
The problem is 3rd party API restricting 45 requests per minute(they are doing throttling and giving 429 ).
if (requestCount < 45)
{
   response = await MakeRequest(json);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {

   }
}
else
{
   //await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
   Thread.Sleep(60000);
   requestCount = 0;
   response = await MakeRequest(json);
}

I am Trying to avoid throttling  by counting the no of requests per minute, once it reach it to 45 I am delaying the process per a minute using Task. Delay.
my azure service bus trigger max concurrent calls to 4, so it is reading 4 at a time.
when it is reached above 45 then it is going to else block its delaying the process per minute,
but the problem is after delaying the process, it's not processing the last 4 messages (45th,46th,47th & 48th).
At first turn it is processing, but once the count is reset to '0' again, it's not processing last 4 messages.
I made max concurrent calls to 1. still when it is getting processed 1 message getting left out.
I tried to use Thread.sleep also it is also giving the same error in c#.

Have you tried not awaiting the delay?

Show all your code please

The fact you are making four concurrent calls and you are not processing the last four requests looks like a clue, but you need to show more of your code

You can find a RateLimiter implementation here, that allows a limited number of actions during a specified timespan.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
